# Llenar Spinner con información de SQLite en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

quiero llenar un Spinner con la información registrada en mi bd SQLite, pero tengo un error al mostrarla en mi ArrayAdapter, el código de mi select es el siguiente:

```
    fun getActivity(idconsumidor: String?): activityModel? {

    var item: activityModel? = null

    val db:SQLiteDatabase = helper?.readableDatabase!!

    val columnas = arrayOf(
        tareoContract.Companion.activityContract.IDCONSUMIDOR,
        tareoContract.Companion.activityContract.DESCRIPCION)

    val c: Cursor = db.query(

        tareoContract.Companion.activityContract.TBL_ACTIVITY,
        columnas,
        " IDCONSUMIDOR = ?",
        arrayOf(idconsumidor),
        null,
        null,
        null

    )

    while(c.moveToNext()){

        item = activityModel(
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.activityContract.IDCONSUMIDOR)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.activityContract.DESCRIPCION))

        )

    }

    c.close()

    return item

}
```

Y aquí es donde lo quiero mostrar:

```
    costProd.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            val seleccion = costProd.selectedItem.toString()
            val activityd= acrud?.getActivity(seleccion)

            val adaptera = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, activityd!!.descripcion.toString())
            activity.adapter = adaptera
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }
```

El error que me sale en el ArrayAdapter es el siguiente:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(p0: Context, p1: Int, p2: Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(p0: Context, p1: Int, p2: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(p0: Context, p1: Int, p2: (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(T)!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

E intentado cambiar mi variable activityd a un ArrayList pero no se como hacerlo, alguien tiene idea de como solucionar el error, me sería de mucha ayuda alguna recomendación.

Answer (score 0):

logré encontrar la solución al problema suscitado:

```
    costProd.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        val seleccion = costProd.selectedItem.toString()
        val activityd= acrud?.getActivity(seleccion)

        val adaptera = ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayListOf<String>(activityd!!.descripcion.toString())) <-- Aquí, metí la respuesta del query dentro de un arrayListOf, también cambié el contexto.
        activity.adapter = adaptera
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

Y con eso quedó solucionado, pasaba que ArrayAdaper no acepta el tipo de dato que le estaba pasando, y lo convertí a un ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentas, el constructor del [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) que usas necesita un List.

Lo que puedes realizar es **convertir el `array` a un `List` usando [arrayListOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html)** de esta forma:

```
val list = arrayListOf(array))
```

Por lo tanto en tu codigo serìa:

```
val adaptera = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayListOf(activityd!!.descripcion.toString()))
```